# How to find look up a list using a string?

Tags: python, list

I have defined the follow string - "string" containing a list name - "list_name":

```
string = "list_name"
```

I also have a list that is called "list_name". How can I look up the list using string?

```
print(string) = "list_name"
print(list_name) # returns the list I need
```

I would like to be able to print(string) and have the actual list returned instead of the string..

Comment: `eval` probably. but this doesn't seem like a good way to structure your code

Comment: You plan ahead and use a dict. `d = {}; d['list_name'] = [...]; print(d[string])`.

Comment: Can you provide extra information as to what the input to `list_name` is as well as the expected output? It is always helpful to have simple inputs and expected outputs. This helps the community to provide better answers.

Comment: I think you are confusing variable names and strings. While you can store a variable name as a string in another variable, that not the usual (or preferred) way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables names are code, not data. If you need dynamic access to one of several lists, then those lists should be values of a `dict`, not just values of distinct variables:

```
d = {
 'list_name': [...],
 'some_other_list': [...]
}

string = "list_name"
print(d[string])
```